# Project Server/PWA - How do you insert a project as a sub-project using the 2016 REST API?

Tags: rest, project-server, ms-project

Given two projects that have been saved and published to Project Server 2016, how can you make one a sub-project of the other (the equivalent of the "Insert Subproject" ribbon button in the client) using the REST API?

I have been looking through the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj712612.aspx), but there are very few examples of how to actually do stuff in Project Server via REST.

From what I can see, a sub-project is represented as a summary task in the master project, the task ID (GUID) is the same as the sub-project's project ID, and there is a property `IsSubProject` that will tell me if the summary task is just a regular summary task or an actual sub-project.

So given a master project, I can find all the sub-projects by grabbing all the tasks that `IsSubProject: true` and then retrieving the projects where the project's ID equals the task's ID.

That's all well and good, but given two unrelated projects, how do I *create* that linkage via REST?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as it turns out, linking sub-projects can only be accomplished through the MS Project desktop client:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee767706.aspx#pj14_WhatPSIDoes_DoesNotDo